# rsync: exclude not working when using a variable

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

Could someone please explain to me this behaviour I noticed lately when I was sync'ing a directory to another server via rsync? I wanted to exclude the sub-directory "done" in this case.

When I put the options to use with rsync into a variable, that directory was not excluded. But it was when I put the options directly behind the rsync call.
Changes to "-av" made a difference, but the exclude didn't work.

rsync 3.0.9-18, on bash, CentOS 7.4

Not excluded:

```
$ RSYNC_OPTIONS='-av --exclude "done"'
$ touch done/test.ignore && rsync ${RSYNC_OPTIONS} ${SOURCEDIR} ${TARGET}
sending incremental file list
done/test.ignore

sent 132 bytes  received 32 bytes  109.33 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Excluded:

```
$ touch done/test.ignore && rsync -av --exclude "done" ${SOURCEDIR} ${TARGET}
sending incremental file list

sent 41 bytes  received 12 bytes  106.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Comment: See this stackoverflow question: [Why do bash parameter expansions cause an rsync command to operate differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527983/why-do-bash-parameter-expansions-cause-an-rsync-command-to-operate-differently)

Comment: I just wasted a whole day (or two) researching what I was doing wrong, and why `--exclude` wasn't working with `--delete`. And it turns out it was this same problem. Ugh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have replicated the problem and used `set -x` to see what the both commands really look like. It turned out this command

```
rsync ${RSYNC_OPTIONS} ${SOURCEDIR} ${TARGET}
```

is in fact equivalent to this

```
rsync -av --exclude '"done"' ${SOURCEDIR} ${TARGET}
```

Note the quotes in quotes. Your pattern is not `done`; it's `"done"`, as if the directory you want to exclude had double quotes in its actual name.

---

To almost fix this you can declare the variable without these troublesome quotes:

```
RSYNC_OPTIONS='-av --exclude done'                           # poor fix, don't
rsync ${RSYNC_OPTIONS} "${SOURCEDIR}" "${TARGET}"
```

But this will backfire if the pattern contains spaces etc. Another approach may be with `eval`:

```
RSYNC_OPTIONS='-av --exclude "name  with  double  spaces"'
eval rsync "${RSYNC_OPTIONS}" '"${SOURCEDIR}" "${TARGET}"'   # not recommended
```

`eval` will parse the line for the second time. It's very hard to use it right and safely. I double quoted `${RSYNC_OPTIONS}` so `"name  with  double  spaces"` doesn't lose double spaces. I single quoted `"${SOURCEDIR}" "${TARGET}"`, so these variables are not expanded right away (otherwise their content would undergo expansion). This is tricky!

Besides, what about `name "with' quotes`? To get this exact string as an option-argument to `rsync --exclude` you need some obscure quoting and escaping in `RSYNC_OPTIONS` declaration. There are more reasons to [avoid `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/10765659).

---

The real solution is to use an array in Bash. Note arrays are not portable.

```
RSYNC_OPTIONS=(-av --exclude 'name with  spaces and $u(h')
rsync "${RSYNC_OPTIONS[@]}" "${SOURCEDIR}" "${TARGET}"
```

I understand why you didn't quote `${RSYNC_OPTIONS}` in your original approach. You should have quoted `${SOURCEDIR}` and (separately) `${TARGET}` though. The above command quotes each variable properly.

Or maybe `${SOURCEDIR}` was meant to specify multiple sources? This would be the reason not to quote it, but then it could bring similar issues as `${RSYNC_OPTIONS}`. In this case you should definitely use an array variable here as well.

Also consider [variable names in lower case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).

Comment: Thanks very much for this thorough explanation! Haven't put the other variables in quotes as those really are constants (I exactly know the one value they contain). Will have a look at the "lower case" link.

Answer (score -1):

What about placing your quotes like this ?

```
RSYNC_OPTIONS='-av --exclude '"done"''
```

---

I only tested it on a simplified command:

```
SEP='-F ";"'
echo "1;2;3" | awk ${SEP} '{print $2}'
```

(not working)

```
SEP='-F '";"''
echo "1;2;3" | awk ${SEP} '{print $2}'
```

(working)

---

**Edit:**

With @Kamil technique, array works well too:

```
SEP=(-F ";")
echo "1;2;3" | awk ${SEP[@]} '{print $2}'
```

Comment: A red herring. `SEP='-F '";"''` defines the same variable value as `SEP='-F ;'` (compare `declare -p SEP` in both cases), therefore your working example is just my "poor fix" in disguise. I downvoted because this answer brings nothing new, except this weird quoting technique that only *obfuscates* the problem.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm a bash newbie, I just like to think there's a workaround with using only strings, but obviously I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, in fact there is a workaround. It involves `eval` and it's rather awful. My answer is now updated to cover this. While I think your answer here is not useful, there are two other answers of yours I upvoted today. In my opinion there's a mishap here, but in general you're doing well.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for adding to your already clear explanation, and for your concern. We do learn a lot from experienced techies like you that are kind enough to take the time to even put the appropriate links to read further. I am ok to be wrong as long as I learn more :) I am just amazed with the Linux World and a bit frustrated not to know 5% of it.